# Img overlay fade, text visible after img fade

Tags: css, hover, overlay

I've learned about everything there is about hover effects and showing text on hover with or without a nice transparent overlay. All beautiful, but none of them answer my question.

I have a "main" image with a transparent overlay image, on hover the overlay image fades out.

All very good and well, But I just want to show a text when the overlay image fades. A very simple effect, I thought..

I've created a JSFiddle to give an idea of the effect.
I've not added any transitions or images, but just the simple effect I seek, but reversed.

So to sum it up, is there a way to make a transparent overlay image fade while text becomes visible, using just CSS and no JavaScript?

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay:hover {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.lay {
  color: #F0F;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: url('');
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 0;
}

.lay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xznjfL0e/)**

Comment: You forgot the CSS in your fiddle

Comment: You have no CSS in your fiddle...
Anyway, have you thought about using [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)? I could probably help you a little bit more once I've seen the effect you're trying to put up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with only CSS, and it's fairly straightforward. Here's the basic idea:

1. Create a wrapper element to hold an image and text.
2. Position the text behind the image so it's not visible
3. On `:hover` of the wrapper, fade the image to reveal the text behind it.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.een {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.een:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}

.een p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity linear 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="een">
  <p class="drie">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Show Me!
  </p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! You've saved me from another sleepless night. I knew it simple, But this simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `transition` on overlay in order to have that fade effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/xznjfL0e/1/

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;/* <=== here */
}
.overlay:hover {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.lay {
  color: #F0F;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: url('');
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 0;
}
.lay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="een">
  <p class="drie">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Show Me!
  </p>
</div>
```